# jquery-select2 always sends null params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using **jquery-select2** to load the data with ajax. But jquery-select2 alwasy send null params to controller action

Here is the **agent.js** code that i am using to search the data

```
$('.chosen-select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Search by Agency code, agent code, name or email",
    ajax: {
      url: "/dashboard/agent_invitations/search_agents",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: function (term) {
        {
          q: term }
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        results: data.results
      }
    }
  });
```

**agents_controller.rb**

```
def search_agents
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: { "data": current_salesperson.search_agents(params[:q]) }} //problem is here
  end
end
```

I followed this link [remote data load](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) to load remote data
Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: If nothing else, formatting your code in a reasonable way would make it much easier to reason about.

Comment: Your data function is a function that doesn't return anything, btw, as is your processResults function-likely not what you want. Matt also want to POST that.

Comment: yeah, missing `return` statement in your `data` function

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks . it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Missing return in data**

```
$('.chosen-select').select2({  
   minimumInputLength:2,
   placeholder:"Search by Agency code, agent code, name or email",
   ajax:{  
      url:"/dashboard/agent_invitations/search_agents",
      dataType:'json',
      type:'GET',
      data:function (term)      {  
        return {   q:term  }
      },
      processResults:function (data)      {  
         results:data.results
      }
   }
});
```