# select2 sending null params to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use select2 multiselect with an ajax call to retrieve the data and filter based on user input, but when it hits the controller the params are null.  Unfortunately (I think because it's custom select2 api) I can't put a chrome breakpoint in the ajax call to mess with it, but the URL looks fine on the network tab.   Right now the ajax calls are written slightly differently, bc I've been trying different solutions; neither work.

I also tried this post, which he said worked, but no dice for me:
[jquery-select2 always sends null params in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150489/jquery-select2-always-sends-null-params-in-controller)

```
$(".filter-agencies").select2({
            //data: agencies,
            ajax: {
                cache: false,
                datatype: 'JSON',
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Home/GetFilterAgency',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {q:params}
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    }
                }
            },
            placeholder: 'Agencies',
            width: '150',
            multiple: true,
            closeOnSelect: false,
            minimumInputLength: 4
            ////tags: true
        });

         $(".filter-advertisers").select2({
            //data: filterSelect,
            ajax: {
                url: 'Home/GetFilterAdvertiser',
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        search: params.term
                    }
                    return query
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    //advertisers = $.map(data, function (obj) {
                    //    obj = { id: i, text: obj }

                    //    i = i + 1;
                    //    return obj
                    //})
                    return {
                        results: data
                    }
                }
            },
            placeholder: 'Advertisers',
            closeOnSelect: false,
            minimumInputLength: 4,
            allowClear: true,
            width: '150',
            multiple: true
        });



        [HttpGet]
        public string GetFilterAdvertiser(string query)
        {
            var x = _orderedLinesProcessor.GetFilterAdvertiser();
            var i = 0;
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            foreach (var el in x)
            {
                dict.Add(i, el);
                i += 1;
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change query to search in controller:

`public string GetFilterAdvertiser(string search)`

Comment: this was the solution, weird that it's not in the documentation. thank you.